# How to debug org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I have a new project and it's my first time using spring MVC and Thymeleaf.
The error message that I'm getting seems obvious:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

I have googled a lot and saw many people with similar issues. However, none of the solutions helped me find out why my setup does not work.

Instead of `classpath:/templates` I have also tried variations like `templates` and `/templates`

**some questions:**

- What is the "basedir" from which the relative path is being looked for?
- Is it possible to run spring in debug to see how these kind of configurations are set? i.e. call when I call localhost:8080 and there's a breakpoint somewhere: would it be possible to see how the file index.html is being looked for?

---

**edit** On line 23 in the document on the right (BetterCommuteApplication.java) you can see that Intellij is able to resolve the reference to my template file.

---

This screenshot shows my configuration and I think it should suffice as enough information to get the answer.

Thank you for your time! :-)

[image: thymeleaf configuration and error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh, I tried to combine Spring boot with thymeleaf manually here. 
(I'm used to developing back-ends ^^")
This doesn't make much sense as initialising spring MVC does this right out of the box.

The solution was to init this as springMVC, use `@Controller` instead of @`Restcontroller` because I want the class to be handled as MVC class... and the return could be as simple as `return 'index'` (because my html file in the default location is called index.html)

basically I would have known, if I'd simply followed [the tutorial on SpringMVC.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).. but hey, why would anyone RTFM? :-)

so it looks like this:

[image: solution]